# Access VBA shell command takes very long to call python script

Tags: python, vba, shell, batch-file, network-drive

I am running Windows 7 with 32 bit versions of Python 2.7 and MS Access 2013.

***What am I doing?***

I am running the below `shell` command in MS Access VBA. It executes a batch file that executes a python script (.py file). All files including the Access database, batch file, python script (.py file) and Python Anaconda installation all sit on a network drive.

```
Public Function XYZ()
Call Shell("cmd /k""G:\foo network drive\xyz.bat"",vbNormalFocus")
End Function
```

***What is my issue?***

When the `shell` command runs, the command prompt pops up on the screen. I can see on the command prompt that the python script has been called from the batch file. But it takes roughly 15 seconds for the python script to start running (I know this because I have the python script print text to the console from beginning to end).

Does anyone have an idea of why it takes so long for the python script to begin running? It makes the process of running the python script much slower.

***Edit given comments***

I am now calling python directly from Access VBA using the below code.

```
Public Function XYZ()
ChDir ("G:\foo network drive")
Call Shell("cmd /k """"G:\foo network drive\Anaconda2\python.exe"" ""G:\foo network drive\bar.py""""")
End Function
```

Unfortunately, it still takes roughly 15 seconds for Python to begin running once the command prompt is shown on screen.

Could this be because python needs time to initially start up? Is there a way to have python start running immediately after the VBA code has run and the command prompt in shown on screen?

Comment: But you can call the python script directly without a batch file.

Comment: Ditto above. You are doing madness. Your quotes are wrong. Try `("cmd /k ""G:\path-to-my-batch-file\xyz.bat""",vbNormalFocus)`. Strings enclosed in 1 set of quotes (and nothing else). For quotes in the string use two quotes.

Comment: I can't attest to why my initial code was working. I think maybe because there are spaces in my file path name. I was calling batch files because I did not realize I have to change my directory before calling python in a network drive